# Какой вариант поиска строки лучше?

Tags: php

Есть два варианта поиска строки определенной. И получение соответственно ключа к нему.Формат ключ => URL. Обычно ищется по строке `URL`.

1.Строка такого вида для первого варианта. `ключ === http://google.com` .Получаем содержимое файла через `file_get_contents()`.Потом через `strpos` получаем строку(ну позицию).Строку разделяем по `explode ('===', $str)`.Получаю ключ по `$str[0]`.

2.Строка вида массива и используются массивы.(key=>11) Массив помещен также как и в первом варианте в файл с помощью `serialize()`.И потом `unserialize`( достаю с `file_get_contents`).Получится массив и с помощью `array_search()` достаю мой заветный ключ к URL.

Какой вариант лучше и почему?

И может свои варианты...

Comment: А это смотря как использовать. Если файл загрузили, одну (нужную) строку нашли - выдали, скрипт завершился - то первый вариант. Хотя я бы как минимум сделал ключ фиксированной длины, если это возможно и не использовал explode. Если файл прочитали и ищем несколько разны строк до завершения скрипта - то второй. А вообще еще можно подумать о хешировании и более сложном формате файла, что бы не читать его весь или использовать СУБД. Так что вариантов гораздо больше двух

Comment: @Mike выступает как база для сайтов. Одна база = 2-50 мб и таких сайтов куча.Не против других вариантов,можно кратко=)

Comment: А почему не хотите какую нибудь СУБД взять, тот же mysql, sqlite и т.п. там уже надо за вас все написано в смысле быстрого поиска

Comment: @Mike Там свои причины и своя оптимизация. Так как на массовость,СУБД может падать. Ну и ещё именно так написан движок. Изначально...И ещё 100500 причин

Comment: А memcached смотрели ? если запросов действительно много - может проще из оперативной памяти быстро получать строки. А если memcached не доступен - поднимать с диска.

Comment: И вы не ответили на главный вопрос - каков цикл жизни php скрипта - запуск - один поиск - завершение. Или запуск и долгая работа с данными в памяти. Я бы при массовой нагрузке возможно вообще сделал fastcgi приложение, что бы скрипты никогда не завершались и держали данные у себя в памяти постоянно. 50 Mb помноженное на десяток одновременно запущенных скриптов не так уж и много

Comment: @Mike MEMCACHE нету увы.Цикл : запуск - поиск - отдача по тому что нашли - умираем.Это сайты.Вот и с диска получаю это дело и ищу.Но запросов должно быть больше чем 10 Поэтому нужно как-то меньше забивать память

Comment: 10 рабочих порцессов fastcgi могут обрабатывать сотни запросов в секунду - если не делают сложных вычислений. И почему вы для второго варианта написали array_rand - вы ищите случайный ключ/строку ?

Comment: Ах, да, еще впорос. вы по url ищете же по точному соответствию - т.е. если url отличается одним символом где то в конце - то это другая строка в файле и другой ключ ?

Comment: @Mike Так точно.А по поводу ренда  - опечатка.Исправлю

Comment: Ладно, люблю делать велосипеды ... сейчас ответ нарисую ...

Comment: @Mike Свой велосипед круче чужого☆

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как известно файловые системы - это неплохие базы данных, при правильном подходе... Предлагаю следующий вариант:

1. от url по которому будем искать получаем какой нибудь быстрый хэш. можно md5, можно функцией [hash()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash.php) например md4 (он вроде самый быстрый из встроенных в php).
2. От строки хеша в шестнадцетиричном виде (типа `8a64c7cb7a794bce2b727acc0362ee27`) получаем первые символы и представляем их в таком виде `/8/a/64`.
3. Получаем `file_get_contents` файл по вычисленному пути, т.е. `you-dir/8/a/64.dat`
4. Разбираем файл как вы предложили, поиском в массиве. Ищем строку. Только строки я предлагаю хранить задом наперед. Т.е. сначала URL потом знак табуляции (`\t`) и ключ. И файл начинать пустой строкой, что бы первым символом шел перевод каретки. Тогда strpos ищем строку `"\n$url\t"` - таким образом мы исключим любые разночтения.

Почему так ? Много файлов в одном каталоге на диске будут сильно тормозить. 256 файлов или каталогов - это не много для чтения одного каталога. Поэтому делаем иерархическую структуру. Делать более 2-3х уровней вложенности - то же плохо, да и смысла не особо много. При данном подходе мы в дерево уложим наши url так, что наш 50Mб файл будет разбит в среднем на куски по 762 байта ...